# Compare custom-field value of entry to registration-form field value before saving user

Tags: plugin-development, registration, entries-field

Whoo, that title is a mouthful...

I'm trying to check against a unique school "code" that an athlete has to input to register with a team. The code is different based on what team they are trying to join (referenced in a segment of registration page URL). I have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to PHP or plugins but I hope I'm on the right track. I have no idea how to test what values my variables have.

I've essentially copied the `user/SaveUser` controller into my own plugin (I have to place user in Athlete user group & related the specific team entry to user, hence custom plugin) and placed snippet below right before the `if (craft()->users->saveUser($user))` line.

```
$teamName = craft()->request->getPost('fields.teamName');
//Get team name, set in hidden input in form, which was grabbed from segment


$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'teams';
$criteria->title   = $teamName;
$criteria->limit   = 1;
$entry = $criteria->first();
//Find the Team entry in my 'teams' section

$schoolCode = $entry->schoolCode;
//Place value of schoolCode field in variable

$codeInput = craft()->request->getPost('fields.schoolCode');
//Grab user's input

if ($schoolCode == $codeInput)
{ 
    craft()->users->saveUser($user)
}
```

This is, of course, not working. I'm not getting any errors either.

Am I anywhere close to doing this right?

Comment: I'd start by `var_dump`ing some variables to see if they have the values you're expecting. `$teamName`, `$schoolCode` and `$codeInput` as a starting point.

Comment: Ah, `var_dump` - I knew there had to be a simple way... That helped. I figured I would have botched the plugin code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Brad Bell, I was able to troubleshoot using `var_dump`. The code above works correctly, but I'm unaware of how to do a simple validation of the code within the controller, w/o creating a new model, & send back a response.

Instead (for simplicity on my end), when the validation fails, I redirected to an error specific page, referencing the code entered & team name.

Comment: Another option to consider is to call your controller via ajax and send back a response — you can then set the error via javascript, and maintain the data that the user has already been entered.